# pyopencl initialize non zero float4 array

Tags: python, numpy, opencl, pyopencl

I want to populate an array with `float4` type. I have no idea how to initialize the arrays with something else than zeros. I've tried variations of this, but this is what I've come with, that explains what I want to do:

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np

kernelSource = """
__kernel void addOneToFloat4(__global float4 *a)
{
    int gid = get_global_id(0);
        a[gid] += 1.0f;
}
"""

context = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(context)
device = context.devices[0]
program = cl.Program(context, kernelSource).build()

N = 10
HOST_array = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0]]*N, dtype=cl.cltypes.float4)
TARGET_array = cl.Buffer(context, cl.mem_flags.READ_WRITE | cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=HOST_array)
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, dest=TARGET_array, src=HOST_array)

program.addOneToFloat4(queue, (N,), None, TARGET_array)

cl.enqueue_copy(queue, dest=HOST_array, src=TARGET_array)
queue.finish()

print(HOST_array)
```

of course it doesn't work, because it understands the input with spahe (N, 4), but since float4 is just a type, it requires (N, ) size.

I've seen people initialize with `np.zeros(N, dtype=float4)`, but I don't want to initialize to 0.

I find very few practical examples for pyopencl, and the [documentation](https://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/search.html?q=float4&check_keywords=yes&area=default#) doesn't always help, it doesn't even mention `float3` or `float4`.

If we look at the OpenCL [documentation](https://rocmdocs.amd.com/en/latest/Programming_Guides/Kernel_language.html?highlight=float4#short-vector-types), we can see that the type float4 is a struct which has `.x, .y, .z, .w` as its fields. It is also declared as a type, so I expect to be able to use it like any other type.

Comment: `HOST_photons` has shape (N,).  `HOST_photons['position']` also has that shape.  So anything you assign to it should also be (N,).

Comment: Yes, so how to convert [0 ,1, 0, 0] into a float4 (which has 1 dimension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching the source code of `pyopencl`, I figured the problem was due to the functions generated on runtime. Also, it is not explicit in the documentation that those functions were available. So to load an array into a `type<n>` you need to call the function `cl.cltypes.make_type<n>` and set the type to `cl.cltypes.type<n>`. Because this is generated at runtime, it will not be in the namespace, so your ide will not recognize them.

```
myFloat4 = cl.cltypes.make_float4(0,1,1,0)
myArrayFloat4 = np.array([myFloat4], dtype=cl.cltypes.float4)
```

So, for completeness, here's my fix:

```
import pyopencl as cl
import numpy as np

kernelSource = """
__kernel void addOneToFloat4(__global float4 *a)
{
    int gid = get_global_id(0);
        a[gid] += 1.0f;
}
"""

context = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(context)
device = context.devices[0]
program = cl.Program(context, kernelSource).build()

N = 10
HOST_array = np.array([cl.cltypes.make_float4(1, 0, 0, 0)]*N, dtype=cl.cltypes.float4)
TARGET_array = cl.Buffer(context, cl.mem_flags.READ_WRITE | cl.mem_flags.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=HOST_array)
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, dest=TARGET_array, src=HOST_array)

program.addOneToFloat4(queue, (N,), None, TARGET_array)

cl.enqueue_copy(queue, dest=HOST_array, src=TARGET_array)
queue.finish()

print(HOST_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the `cl` stuff, here's a sample array creation

```
In [50]: myStruct = np.dtype(
    ...:         [("position", float),
    ...:          ("direction", float),
    ...:          ("er", float),
    ...:          ("weight", float)])

In [55]: arr = np.zeros(5,myStruct)
In [56]: arr
Out[56]: 
array([(0., 0., 0., 0.), (0., 0., 0., 0.), (0., 0., 0., 0.),
       (0., 0., 0., 0.), (0., 0., 0., 0.)],
      dtype=[('position', '<f8'), ('direction', '<f8'), ('er', '<f8'), ('weight', '<f8')])
In [57]: arr['position']
Out[57]: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
In [58]: arr['position']=np.arange(5)
In [59]: arr['direction']=3
In [60]: arr['er']=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5]])
In [61]: arr['weight']=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5]]).T
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [61] in <cell line: 1>
    arr['weight']=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5]]).T
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,1) into shape (5,)
```

Comment: The type I'm looking for is the vector type `float4`, I've added precisions on the documentation of `float4` in my question. `3` is not a direction, `direction`, `position` and `er` are supposed to be vector types `float4`, because they are vectors, not scalars.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about `cl` or `float4`, so can't help.  What does `myStruct` display as?

Comment: it display as this: `typedef struct {
  float4 position;
  float4 direction;
  float4 er;
  float weight;
} photonStruct;`, when I look at the opencl declaration created by `match_dtype_to_c_struct`. The question is really about `cl` stuff unfortunately, which is very not beginner friendly (like me).